# /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by myproject) in C

Tags: c

> /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /home/ubuntu/CLionProjects/DailyCode/CCodes/cmake-build-debug/CCodes)

I have aready installed curl and have checked its version ,but when i running this  project ,it always warning me the error . But it can still work , how to solve this problem ?

```
ubuntu@shan-android:~$ curl --version
curl 7.63.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.63.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0g
Release-Date: 2018-12-12
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy 

/home/ubuntu/CLionProjects/DailyCode/CCodes/cmake-build-debug/CCodes
/home/ubuntu/CLionProjects/DailyCode/CCodes/cmake-build-debug/CCodes: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /home/ubuntu/CLionProjects/DailyCode/CCodes/cmake-build-debug/CCodes)
```

//here is my core code , it has no special ,an simple for testing curl ,and code is correct

void test_post_method() {
    int nCode = -1;

```
char *ip = "220.181.57.216";
char *url_path = NULL;
int port = 80;
char *user = "USER";//no use 
char *pwd = "PWD";//no use 
int format = FORMAT_JSON;
st_curl_params curl_params;
curl_init_params(&curl_params, ip, url_path, port, user, pwd, format);


st_curl_rec curl_rec;


int method = METHOD_GET;

char *msg = "{\"UserName\":\"user\",\"UserPwd\":\"pwd\"}";//no use 
CURL *curl = NULL;
curl = curl_init_resource();
nCode = send_msg(curl, &curl_params, "", method, &curl_rec);
DPRINT("post:\n%s\nsize:%d\n", curl_rec.rec, curl_rec.len);
curl_release_resource(curl);
```

}

Comment: What is `CCodes`? Is it a program you've written? Show the code that's getting the error.

Comment: The `curl` package is irrelevant for development. For development, you need the `libcurl4-openssl-dev` package (seeing as your `curl` uses the OpenSSL variant already).